# Using a stored procedure, get the error: ERROR 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'users'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, procedure

Im new to SQL, I currently use it alot for my new apprenticeship and I'm trying to get a better grasp of it at home. Currently i have a simple PHP script for creating a user to a database, and now want to extract data from multiple tables based on the User's ID, But i am getting this error;

```
ERROR 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'users'

SQL Statement:

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_userinfo`(IN uName VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN

SELECT id,password,salt,email FROM controlpanel.users

LEFT JOIN controlpanel.users ON users.id=servers.ServerID



WHERE username = uName;

END
```

Im currently using MySQL.
I am attempting to get columns ServerID, Port, IP, NodeID from the table 'servers' where the column 'OwnerID' = 'id' in the 'users' table.

Comment: Both sides of your `LEFT JOIN` are on `controlpanel.users`. It looks like you mean for one of the two to be `servers`.

Comment: you're joining `users` to `users` without giving it an alias. However, it looks like you meant `servers`.

Comment: right I see, so it should be LEFT JOIN controlpanel.servers ON users.id=servers.ServerID ?

Comment: @JamesTrotter it would seem unlikely that the servers.ServierID corresponds to the users.id column. Why are join joining onto the servers table anyway?

Comment: You're correct that users.id should of infacted linked to server.OwnerID, and youre correct i should of been joining them. I relaised this shortly after, and replaced it with a new stored procedure to get all servers with the user id provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an incorrect method for what I wanted to achieve, and to my current belief I should take the "id" field from the users table and then run another stored procedure using that to find all the rows where the users.id = servers.OwnerID